# Alert in ViewModel

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I am using the `Acr.Dialogs` as follows, to display dialog box.
However, it seems it only supports one button which is `OK`. However, I want to have `Cancel` and `OK` buttons.

**ViewModel.cs**

```
var alertConfig = new AlertConfig
{
   Message = "Are you sure?",
   OnOk = () => {
      NotifyUpdated();
    },
};
Mvx.Resolve<IUserDialogs>().Alert(alertConfig);
```

Comment: If you have more than one button, at that point its not an alert, it's a *prompt*.

Comment: Ok, I am looking `prompt` then.

Comment: Conceptually speaking, an alert is simply something that the user acknowledges - it's not meaningful to "cancel" an alert.  If there is a decision to be made, it's now prompting for user input.

Comment: A prompt in the ACR.UserDialog library is used to collect input from the user via a text box field. Alert is mostly to inform the user while not expecting a response. Confirm is used to inform the user and expect a bool in response. You can change the text from "OK", "Cancel" to "Yes", "No" or whatever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Confirmation dialogs have OK and Cancel by default. You could use `Task<bool> IUserDialogs.ConfirmAsync(string message, string title = null, string okText = null, string cancelText = null, CancellationToken? cancellationToken)` method instead.

```
var confirm = await Mvx.Resolve<IUserDialogs>().ConfirmAsync("Are you sure?");
if (confirm)
{
    NotifyUpdated();
}
else
{
    // User pressed Cancel
}
```

If you want to keep things synchronous you could use this code:

```
Mvx.Resolve<IUserDialogs>().Confirm(new ConfirmConfig
{
    OnAction = b =>
    {
        if (b)
        {
            NotifyUpdated();
        }
        else
        {
            // User pressed Cancel
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I do not see cancellation in your given example?

Comment: I've updated the example code to show how to handle cancel. If you mean to close the dialog programmatically then you should take a look [here](https://github.com/aritchie/userdialogs/issues/68).